# Excel check if cell contains text from list and return values from list for every match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of products with Material no and Text description as visible in Sheet1 image.
Every part of the text has a defined value in another sheet.

How to get result in Sheet1 column C for each product based on its Text description and appropriate values defined in Sheet2?
Let's say I would like to parse the text and for each part of text to determine the value from another sheet and summarize this to one number.

For example:
Material 1 has A B C D in Text, formula should result with 100 => 10+20+30+40 (A=10+B=20+C=30+D=40)
etc...

I know I can use IF to check for each variant then return value with vlookup, but this is something I would like to avoid. Variants will change, their number can be pretty big therefore I would like to avoid changing formulas every time when we change Variants...

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Hi, my version is: Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.10730.20416) 32 bit
Perfectly fine if it was a sum of all variant costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking by your screenshots you have a version of Excel prior to Micrososft365. In that case I think you can use:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&E$2:E$11&" "," "&B2&" "))*F$2:F$11)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working very well for me!